# How to read Import Address Table, in a driver, from a PEPROCESS?

Tags: c++, c, windbg, drivers, portable-executable

I am coding a driver in order to create an *Antivirus*. However, I am stuck in reading the import address table from a process.

I have a **CreateProcessNotify**:

```
VOID CreateProcNotify(HANDLE  ParentId, HANDLE  ProcessId, BOOLEAN Create)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ParentId);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Create);
    PEPROCESS Process;
    KAPC_STATE Apc;
    PVOID ModuleBase;

    // From PID to PEPROCESS
    PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessId, &Process);

    // Attach into the target process' memory
    KeStackAttachProcess(Process, &Apc);

    ModuleBase = GetModuleBase(Process);

    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pImportAddressTable = GetIAT(ModuleBase);

    DPrint("Imports of [Meias] are: \n");
    DPrint("IAT: %x\n", pImportAddressTable);
    // Iterate all Modules Imports
    while (pImportAddressTable->Name != 0) {
        DPrint("{%s}, ", (PCHAR)((ULONG)ModuleBase + (pImportAddressTable->Name)));

        pImportAddressTable++;
    }

    // Unattach ourselves from the target process' memory
    KeUnstackDetachProcess(&Apc);
}
```

While also having the following functions:

```
/*Returns the Base of the Process*/
PVOID GetModuleBase(PEPROCESS Process)
{
    PVOID ModuleBase;

    __try
    {
        ModuleBase = PsGetProcessSectionBaseAddress(Process);
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return ModuleBase;
}

/*Returns the Import Address Table*/
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR GetIAT(PVOID ModuleBase)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)ModuleBase;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 pNtHeader32 = NULL;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 pNtHeader64 = NULL;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pIAT = NULL;

    if (ModuleBase == 0)
        return NULL;

    DPrint("ModuleBase: 0x%x\n", pDosHeader);

    // If the magic value isn't MZ then isn't a valid PE
    if (pDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;

    pNtHeader32 = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)((PUCHAR)ModuleBase + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
    pNtHeader64 = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)((PUCHAR)ModuleBase + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);

    // If the image doesn't have a DOS
    if ((INT)pNtHeader32 != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;

    // Check if is 32 bit
    if (pNtHeader32->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC) {
        pIAT = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((ULONG_PTR)ModuleBase + pNtHeader32->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    }
    // Check if is 64 bit
    else if (pNtHeader64->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC) {
        pIAT = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((ULONG_PTR)ModuleBase + pNtHeader64->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    }

    return pIAT;
}
```

When debugging with WinDBG:

[image: The exception it throw]

Using the **!analyze -v**:

The exception: 
[image]

The code:
[image]

I implemented the GetIAT with the help of [this](https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/blob/master/src/BlackBoneDrv/Loader.c#300)

As you can see the problem is that it isn't getting the IAT properly but I don't know why...

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was because I was using

```
if ((INT)pNtHeader32 != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;
```

When I should be checking the Signature of it:

```
if ((INT)pNtHeader32->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

The code of **IAT** function is unreliable. If **Import Table Address** is 0 it will be a reason for **BSOD**.

For example, this [project](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) (to analyze dependencies; *remake* of the old legacy software **depends.exe**) has **Import Table Address** is 0.

[image]

For avoiding **BSOD** you need to add a check, like this:

```
...
    // Check if is 32 bit
    if (pNtHeader32->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC) {
        if (pNtHeader32->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress == 0)
            return NULL;

        pIAT = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((ULONG_PTR)ModuleBase
            + pNtHeader32->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    }
    // Check if is 64 bit
    else if (pNtHeader64->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC) {
        if (pNtHeader64->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress == 0)
            return NULL;

        pIAT = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((ULONG_PTR)ModuleBase + pNtHeader64->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    }
...
```